# Hi, class not applied to input element on focus

Tags: css, reactjs

i am currently trying to apply red class to input element based on its validation. If input element is invalid then i update the state of red to red class. This works but i have the red class applied on no focus to input element. for the first time input becomes invalid, the red class doesnt apply. however once input element has no focus it applies the style and stays like that even after focus or no focus. What am i doing wrong. could someone help. thanks.

```
handle_validate = (event) => {
    if((event.target.value.length > 0  && this.state.has_focus) || (event.target.value.length === 0 && this.state.has_focus)){
        if (!event.target.validity.valid) {
            if (event.target.validity.patternMismatch) {
                this.setState({is_valid: false});
                this.setState({red: 'red'});
            }else {
               this.setState({red: ''});
            }};
          return (
             <div>
                 <input {...rest}
                    className={this.state.red }/>
             </div>


input.red{
    border-color: red;
}
```

Comment: This is within React, right?

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that you WANT the style applied only on focus, you would need to do something like this:

```
input.red:focus { 
    border-color: red;
}
```

This would also mean that when there is no focus, the style disappears. You don't need the && this.state.has_focus) bit. Nothing will input anyhow if there is no focus.

However, your other problem seems to be that the class doesn't get added until there is no more focus. This is related to how react (I assume this is react code) handles user input. Can't help you there without more of your code.